# If natural diamond was large and abundant how would it change the world?

Tags: materials

Watching my kids play Minecraft, I was reminded of a children's novel I enjoyed many years ago called *Twenty-One Balloons* about a clan that discovered a vast deposit of diamond on a small volcanic island.

**Suppose that natural diamond was found on earth in such concentration and abundance as coal.  Could that enable any technology or have any discernable impact on modern society?**  (Other than to remove diamond from use as a store of value?)

I'm having a hard time imagining any significant benefits that might accrue from convenient access to large diamond crystals.  Although diamond is extremely hard, it is also quite brittle, so I don't think that any large cutting tool could be fashioned from solid diamond that isn't already made (and more durably) from industrial diamond specks bound to metal substrates.

I could imagine diamond being a luxury building material, like other polished stone slabs and blocks.  Indeed, the fundamental difficulty of cutting and working it would probably keep its status as the most luxurious architectural material, even if crushed diamond was otherwise being used as a fuel like coal.

Comment: If this deposit was found nowadays? It already sort of has been found. Diamond is incredibly common and artificially creating them is very simple. In addition diamond is not used as a store of value, because it is so plentiful.

Comment: @AngelPray: I wouldn't say that diamonds are incredibly common, but they are common enough that there are stories about the DeBeers cartel dumping them into the sea in order to keep the price up.

Comment: Probably the diamond sellers would try to buy this diamond and make it disappear to keep the prices artificially high, like they are now. Diamonds aren't worth nearly as much as you're expected to pay for them.

Comment: In a non serious aspect, our cultural perspective of diamonds would also change.  As such in games like Minecraft diamonds would not be such a precious ore to find.

Comment: @AngelPray - I'm talking about *abundant* deposits of *large* diamonds.  Imagine a diamond *quarry* like a coal seam where you might routinely find crystals weighing tens of pounds in blocks weighing hundreds of tons that approach 99% diamond.  Artificial diamond crystals cannot yet be produced in sizes much greater than a carat or two, and their wholesale production cost is still tremendous.

Comment: @feetwet, Congo by Michael Crichton (although IMHO one of his poorer books) is about an expedition into the jungle to find natural diamonds to use in semiconductors.  Probably worth a read, but plz don't judge Critchon's work based on that one.

Comment: Diamond is sort of a really pure form of coal.  I wonder how it burns.

Comment: Diamonds burn about as well as coal so they could be used as fuel. I wonder how hard it is to make diamond lenses.

Comment: @John - The lens idea crossed my mind, but I couldn't think of any value they'd add over existing optical crystals and coatings that would justify the massive increase in difficulty to grind them.  However, *if* natural diamond crystals occurred in sufficient size and purity they could overtake [sapphire as a premium scratch-proof glass for watches, tablets](http://www.cultofmac.com/267068/everything-wanted-know-sapphire-glass-afraid-ask-qa/), etc.; because diamond can be flat-cut by laser.

Answer (score 12):

**Cheaper, bigger pieces of diamond would *revolutionize* engineering, if engineers got to use it, instead of jewelers.**

In engineering/tech, diamond has many potential uses that go unexploited, because diamond is too expensive or not available in the size/purity needed.  Here are three engineering uses, to start you off:

1. Higher-power, faster electronics, using diamond semiconductors (instead of silicon): http://spectrum.ieee.org/nanoclast/semiconductors/materials/diamondbased-semiconductors-take-a-step-foward
2. Durable, low friction material for bearings, engine cylinders or piston rings: 
   http://ussbearings.com/bearings_site/research_article/949/
3. Heat transfer: we often need to move lots of heat in Engineering (engines, power-hungry CPUs, spacecraft) and diamond conducts heat about *five* times better than copper.  Now that synthetic diamond is coming on stream, using diamond for thermal issues is possible:
   http://www.diamond-materials.com/EN/cvd_diamond/thermal_properties.htm

This is just scratching the surface.  Synthetic diamond is also used in machining metals or other hard materials.  (Except for steel or other alloys containing carbon; diamond tools 'dissolve' into the piece being cut, an expensive mistake!)

Comment: Are applications #1 and #3 possible using *natural* diamonds?  I'm familiar with synthetic diamond and diamond-like *coatings* for these characteristics, but it's unclear to me whether natural diamond crystals could be effectively used for these purposes.

Comment: @feetwet, since this is a diamond deposit unlike any known in earthly geology (unless DeBeers is *really* good at keeping secrets!), we can only *speculate* on the crystal quality.  #1 needs low, low defects, whereas bearings and heat xfer aren't quite so  fussy.

Comment: Silicon semiconductors are shaped in manufacture.  Presumably synthetic diamond semiconductors are also shaped during manufacture.  Natural diamonds would be unlikely to have the exact structure that they need.  High quality is possible, but not with the desired pathways.

Comment: @Brythan, diamond has a cubic crystal structure and it cleaves easily.  If there are nice big (inch or larger) diamonds for cheap, those can be cleaved into flat pieces, especially thin flat pieces, pretty much what's needed for IC fabrication.  If the crystals are even bigger, so much the better!

Comment: Semiconductors are made by depositing various substances on very thin slices of ultra-pure silicon.  Even supposing that you could find large natural diamonds of the needed purity, what the heck would you use to cut them into thin slices?

Comment: @jamesqf: "What the heck would you use to cut them into thin slices" -- not cut, but _cleave_ by applying a short, sharp shock.

Comment: "This is just scratching the surface."  Heh – I see what you did there ;)

Comment: @AlexP: I really, really doubt that you are going to manage to reliably get slices 300 mm in diameter and less than 1 mm thick (the size of wafer used in Intel's current CPUs) by cleavage.  It then has to be polished to extreme smoothness.  The wafer has to be free of crystal defects, which is unlikely to happen with a naturally-occuring crystal.  Even the small diamonds we use for jewelery usually have flaws that are visible under low magnification, if not with the unaided eye.

Comment: @jamesqf: while silicon is mainly at 300 mm diameter wafers, diamond isn't there, nor does it need to be.  For many viable markets (e.g. high power semiconductors), smaller wafers would be snapped up!  Seriously, I'd *love* to be in a position to offer even a few 50 mm diam. or even 25 mm diamond wafers for sale!  Cleaving has worked quite well on the largest cut diamonds documented.  I'm not certain thin diamond layers are easy to cleave, but the cleavage planes of diamond are just about ideal, cartesian axes.  (It's just that trying it has been too expensive, I suppose.)